# ErrorException in Collection.php line 1043: Undefined offset: 0 in laravel

Tags: php, jquery, laravel

controller: HomeController.php

```
public function index()
{

    // home page redirect query
    $data['redirect'] = SiteSettings::where('name','default_home')->get();
    $data['popular_rooms'] = Rooms::where('status','Listed')->get();
    $data['property_rooms'] = PropertyRooms::select("property_room.*","rooms_photos.name", "rooms_price.night")
        ->join("rooms_photos","rooms_photos.room_id","=","property_room.room_id")
        ->join("rooms_price","rooms_price.room_id","=","property_room.room_id")
        ->where('rooms_photos.featured','Yes')
        ->get();        

    $data['city_count']    = HomeCities::all()->count();
    $data['result']        = ThemeSettings::get();
    $data['browser'] = '';
    if(isset($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'])) 
    {
        $agent = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];
        if(strlen(strstr($agent,"Chrome")) > 0 ) 
        {      
            $data['browser'] = 'chrome';
        }
    }

    $data['home_page_media'] = SiteSettings::where('name', 'home_page_header_media')->first()->value;
    $data['home_page_sliders'] = Slider::whereStatus('Active')->orderBy('order', 'asc')->get();
    $data['home_page_bottom_sliders'] = BottomSlider::whereStatus('Active')->orderBy('order', 'asc')->get();
    $data['host_banners'] = HostBanners::all();
    $data['home_city']     = HomeCities::all();
    $data['languagess'] =  Language::where('default_language', '1')->first()->value;

    $data['bottom_sliders'] = BottomSlider::whereStatus('Active')->orderBy('order', 'asc')->get();
    $data['our_community_banners'] = OurCommunityBanners::limit(3)->get(); 

    //home page two data start    
   $data['reservation'] = Reservation::orderBy('id', 'desc')->where('status','Accepted')->groupBy('room_id')->limit(10)->get(); 
   $data['view_count'] = Rooms::orderBy('views_count', 'desc')->where('status','Listed')->groupBy('id')->get(); 
   $data['recommented'] = Rooms::orderBy('id', 'desc')->where('recommended','Yes')->where('status','Listed')->groupBy('id')->get(); 
   $data['res_count'] = count($data['reservation']);
   $data['room_view_count'] = count($data['view_count']);
   $data['room_recommented_view'] = count($data['recommented']) ;  

     //redirect home page
    if($data['redirect'][0]->value == 'home_two') 
    { 
        $data['default_home'] = 'two' ;return view('home.home_two',$data);
    } 
    else   
    {   
        return view('home.home', $data);  
    }  
}
```

route:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['install','locale']], function () {    
    Route::get('/', 'HomeController@index');
});
```

In this code I have to run my index file inside the controller but when I server php artisan it throw an offset error i.e. `ErrorException in Collection.php line 1043: Undefined offset: 0`. I don't know why where I am doing wrong? Please help me.

Thank You

Answer (score 0):

You need to check that the index is present before accessing it.

`isset($data['redirect'][0])`

```
if(isset($data['redirect'][0])) {
    if($data['redirect'][0]->value == 'home_two') { 
        $data['default_home'] = 'two';
        return view('home.home_two',$data);
    } 
}
```